# How animate margin in UWP?

Tags: xaml, animation, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I'm try use

```xml
    <animations:AnimationCollection x:Name="UnHoverCollection">
      <animations:Vector2Animation To="10,10" Target="Margin" />
    </animations:AnimationCollection>
```

and this animations

```xml
    <animations:AnimationCollection x:Name="UnHoverCollection">
      <animations:Vector4Animation To="10,10,10,10" Target="Margin" />
    </animations:AnimationCollection>
```

and take next error

> "The specified property was not found or cannot be animated. Context:
>   Margin Expression: Margin Start Position: 0, End Position: 6"

How do this animation?

Comment: may be you could use just `RepositionThemeTransition` ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.RepositionThemeTransition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move the object, animating the margin is not a good idea. These animation types are mainly operated according to X, Y coordinate. I suggest that you can use TranslationAnimation or OffsetAnimations. You can refer to this [document](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WindowsCommunityToolkitDocs/blob/master/docs/animations/CompositionAnimations.md) to move the object.